# Does a GLM where the dependent variable is a rate without offset produce the same result when a count with offset is used?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, statsmodels, offset

I have the following two models in Python:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import glm

model1 = glm(" rate ~ explanatory variables", data=df, family=sm.families.Poisson())
model2 = glm("count ~ explanatory variables", data=df, family=sm.families.Poisson(), offset=np.log(df.exposure))
```

where rate is defined as $\text{rate} = \dfrac{\text{count}}{\text{exposure}}$.

I would expect these models to produce the same result, but they do not. The results are similar but not identical. My reasoning why they should be similar is as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\log(\text{rate})&= \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1+...+\beta_nX_n + \epsilon \hspace{1cm}\text{(model 1)}
\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\\
\log\left(\frac{\text{count}}{\text{exposure}}\right) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1+...+\beta_nX_n + \epsilon
\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\\
\log(\text{count}) - \log(\text{exposure}) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1+...+\beta_nX_n + \epsilon
\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\\
\log(\text{count}) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1+...+\beta_nX_n + \log(\text{exposure}) + \epsilon \hspace{0.5cm}\text{(model 2)}
\end{align*}$$

That is, if I add the logarithm of a variable that measures exposure and fix the coefficient at 1, the models are similar.

**Question**:
What is the difference between `model1` ($\text{model 1}$) and `model2` ($\text{model 2}$)?

**My attempt to an answer**:
The variable `count` from `model2` has, by definition, a Poisson distribution. But what about the variable `rate` from `model1`? It is a continuous variable, so the distribution definitely should not be Poisson, right? My current understanding is that we use `model1`, because its distribution is known and easy to fit. I think both models will lead to the same coefficients, but maybe `model2` follows the distribution more closely and is therefore more efficient. This increased efficiency leads to smaller standard errors (but the same unbiased coefficients).

---

UPDATE: So `model1` is wrong, because it does not take into account exposure at all. Another approach of modelling `model2` is `model3` as specified below (they are equivalent):

```
model3 = glm("rate ~ explanatory variables", var_weights=df.exposure, data=df, family=sm.families.Poisson())
```

Comment: What results differ, params or only standard errors bse, cov_params? standard errors cannot be correct in your rate regression because there is no correct information about total sample size nobs * exposure.

Comment: Coefficients (params) are also different

Comment: see var_weights  for averaged y, i.e. rate or proportion https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/glm_weights.html#aggregated-or-averaged-data-(unique-values-of-explanatory-variables)

Comment: I think params should be the same if `exposure=exposure` or `offset = log(exposure)` in the second model, but not bse.

Comment: exposure=exposure and offset=log(exposure) do indeed produce the same result, however the result is not similar to model1 in the question.

Answer (score 4):

They are different models. Write $Y$ for the count and $T$ for the exposure time, and $X$ for predictors.  One model says
$$\log\,E\left[\frac{Y}{T}\mid X=x\right]=x\beta$$
The other says
$$\log E[Y|X=x,T=t]=x\beta+\log t$$
and so
$$\log \frac{E[Y|X=x,T=t]}{t}=x\beta$$

Since the expectation of a ratio isn't the ratio of the expectations, these are different in general.  On top of that, the standard errors will be wrong for a Poisson (as opposed to quasi-Poisson) model in the first case, because $Y/T$ doesn't have a Poisson distribution (it's not even *integers*)

They might be the same in some cases. For example, if $X$ is just a single factor variable and $T$ is constant within each group, the first model will reproduce the mean of $Y/T$ within each group, which is the same as the mean of $Y$ in the  group divided by the common value of $T$, which is the same as the second model.

Comment: with the caveat that in the Poisson case $E[Y|X=x, T=t] = t * E[Y|X=x, t=1]$. So x * beta is the expectation of Y for one unit of exposure in the second case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I am still note sure which method is correct. Since the ratio is non-integer I believe my `model1` is definitely wrong. I need to use some offset if I want to use the Poisson distribution, but what should the offset be? My current understanding is that the offset should be $g(T)$ where $g$ is the same link function used for $Y$.

Comment: The second method is correct with `offset=log(exposure)` (which in statsmodels is the same as using the keyword `exposure=exposure`.) It only works for log link because exposure needs to be multiplicative in poisson mean function.

Answer (score 3):

Use exposure as a weight when fitting the rate model.

Here's an example demonstrating this advice. The data is from the famous British Doctors Study. The outcome is coronary disease deaths among doctors of different ages (in decade buckets), some of whom smoked. During the course of the study, the physicians would age across category boundaries, so a person-years approach was used to handle exposure:

```
. webuse dollhill3, clear
(Doll and Hill (1966))

. gen rate = deaths/pyears

. list, clean noobs 

    agecat   smokes   deaths   pyears       rate  
     35–44        1       32   52,407   .0006106  
     45–54        1      104   43,248   .0024047  
     55–64        1      206   28,612   .0071998  
     65–74        1      186   12,663   .0146885  
     75–84        1      102    5,317   .0191837  
     35–44        0        2   18,790   .0001064  
     45–54        0       12   10,673   .0011243  
     55–64        0       28    5,710   .0049037  
     65–74        0       28    2,585   .0108317  
     75–84        0       31    1,462   .0212038  

. glm rate smokes i.agecat [weight=pyears], family(poisson) nolog
(frequency weights assumed)
note: rate has noninteger values

Generalized linear models                         Number of obs   =    181,467
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =    181,461
                                                  Scale parameter =          1
Deviance         =  12.13236755                   (1/df) Deviance =   .0000669
Pearson          =  11.15533109                   (1/df) Pearson  =   .0000615

Variance function: V(u) = u                       [Poisson]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                   [Log]

                                                  AIC             =   .0428816
Log likelihood   = -3884.795554                   BIC             =   -2197268

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 OIM
        rate | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      smokes |   .3545356   .1073741     3.30   0.001     .1440862     .564985
             |
      agecat |
      45–54  |   1.484007   .1951034     7.61   0.000     1.101611    1.866402
      55–64  |   2.627505   .1837273    14.30   0.000     2.267406    2.987604
      65–74  |   3.350493   .1847992    18.13   0.000     2.988293    3.712693
      75–84  |   3.700097   .1922195    19.25   0.000     3.323354     4.07684
             |
       _cons |  -7.919326   .1917618   -41.30   0.000    -8.295172   -7.543479
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. glm deaths smokes i.agecat, exposure(pyears) family(poisson) nolog

Generalized linear models                         Number of obs   =         10
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =          4
                                                  Scale parameter =          1
Deviance         =   12.1323664                   (1/df) Deviance =   3.033092
Pearson          =   11.1553332                   (1/df) Pearson  =   2.788833

Variance function: V(u) = u                       [Poisson]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                   [Log]

                                                  AIC             =   7.920031
Log likelihood   = -33.60015344                   BIC             =   2.922026

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 OIM
      deaths | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      smokes |   .3545356   .1073741     3.30   0.001     .1440862     .564985
             |
      agecat |
      45–54  |   1.484007   .1951034     7.61   0.000     1.101611    1.866403
      55–64  |   2.627505   .1837273    14.30   0.000     2.267406    2.987604
      65–74  |   3.350493   .1847992    18.13   0.000     2.988293    3.712693
      75–84  |   3.700096   .1922195    19.25   0.000     3.323353     4.07684
             |
       _cons |  -7.919326   .1917618   -41.30   0.000    -8.295172   -7.543479
  ln(pyears) |          1  (exposure)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. glm rate smokes i.agecat, family(poisson) nolog
note: rate has noninteger values

Generalized linear models                         Number of obs   =         10
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =          4
                                                  Scale parameter =          1
Deviance         =  .0015654072                   (1/df) Deviance =   .0003914
Pearson          =  .0015207074                   (1/df) Pearson  =   .0003802

Variance function: V(u) = u                       [Poisson]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                   [Log]

                                                  AIC             =   1.278873
Log likelihood   = -.3943625936                   BIC             =  -9.208775

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 OIM
        rate | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      smokes |   .1441225   6.991483     0.02   0.984    -13.55893    13.84718
             |
      agecat |
      45–54  |    1.59365   40.96306     0.04   0.969    -78.69247    81.87977
      55–64  |   2.826107   38.43478     0.07   0.941    -72.50468    78.15689
      65–74  |   3.572085    37.8655     0.09   0.925    -70.64293     77.7871
      75–84  |   4.031138   37.67455     0.11   0.915    -69.80962    77.87189
             |
       _cons |  -8.008174   37.53203    -0.21   0.831    -81.56959    65.55325
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the weighted GLM rate model matches the one with exposure, while omitting the weight leads to divergence.

Comment: Thank for this reference material, but I can't just apply some approach because the results make sense. I need to have an understanding of the math.

Comment: I think of this as a consequence of $E[E[Y \vert X, P] \vert X]=E[Y \vert X]$. If you think of each age x smoker group as a discrete X, then weighting is just doing that outer expectation. Your mistake is thinking you can just divide by P and pull it into the expectation.